# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0'

Tags: php

I am trying to log in with 3 types of users in laravel 8, admin, teacher and student, but when I log in I get the following error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `0` in (OWxc4iUiHyKTY92N55CN1B6SGQfCoXZ2b5kod0it, admin@admin.com) limit 1)

this is the code of **LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {  
        $inputVal = $request->all();


    $this->validate($request, [
         'email' => 'required|email',
         'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt(array(['email' => $inputVal, 'password' => $inputVal]))){
        if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 0) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.route');
        }
        if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('Teacher.route');
        }
        if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('Student.route');
        }

    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')
            ->with('error','Correo & Contraseña son incorrectos.');
    }     
}
```

this is the code in the migration **create_user_table**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
//tabla para registrar usuarios
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->enum('is_admin', [0,1,2])->default(2);
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**model User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\SocialPorfiles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'is_admin',
        'password',

        
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //relacion con los registros del socialite socialporfile
    public function SocialPorfiles(){
        return $this->hasMany(SocialPorfile::class, 'user_id');
    }

}
```

**MODEL SocialPorfile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class SocialPorfile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    //relacion con la tabla user
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'social_id', 'social_name', 'social_avatar'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the old array syntax(`array()`) with the new array syntax(`[]`). And you pass all parameters to both arguments(`$inputVal`) Try using the following:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
```

in the `public function login(Request $request)` method of the `LoginController`.

Comment: i am using that condition if(Auth::attempt(array(['email' => $inputVal, 'password' => $inputVal]))){
            if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 0) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.route');
            }

Comment: but the error continues

Comment: Did you replace the `Auth::attempt` with the one I provided? Your example is invalid, you should remove the `array(...)`  and only keep the values within the `[` and `]`

Comment: if i use if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $inputVal, 'password' => $inputVal])){   without array i have the next error     password_verify(): Argument #1 ($password) must be of type string, array given

Comment: That is because you use `$inputVal` that contains an array itself, check the updated example :)

Comment: tank you, your comments were of great help to me

Comment: Great! Could you mark the answer as solution using the checkmark or upvote it to help others find it?

Comment: yes, sure, right away